# Page numbers in a PDF are off, how can I change them?

Tags: windows, linux, pdf, pdfedit

I have a digital edition of textbook I bought. The pages are numbered from 1 - 570.

As a result, when I search page 68, it shows page 51 as the first pages originally in the textbook aren't numbered and there's a whole index of some numbered as `XVII`.

What can I do to edit this textbook, or change the page numbers accordingly?

Comment: the answer where you can fix this by editing the pdf directly with a text editor: http://superuser.com/a/430628/129520 (because [real programmers](https://xkcd.com/378/) edit pdfs directly; and also because it's *quite a fun* :).)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have Adobe Acrobat, this is really simple:

1. Open the document,
2. Select the thumbnails that you want to renumber (the first x pages)
3. Right-click, number pages (or Advanced-> Document Processing-> Number Pages
4. Adjust these settings, and click 'ok'

That should shift your start page, and add in you roman numeral pages.

**Update for 2024:**

3. Right-click, select *Page Labels*
4. Adjust these settings, and click 'ok'

Comment: i use foxit is it possible in it?

Comment: Foxit only reads PDFs, AFAIK, so I don't think this can be done with that application.

Answer (score 2):

You could always put the numbered content pages in a separate document where the page numbers matched.  Then place any "un-numbered" pages in reference documents.  So if the table of contents is in the first 17 pages place it in a T.O.C. document.  Then have a content document where page 1 is the first page, then an index document where you could look up page numbers and find them correctly in the content.  Splitting and merging PDF files is quite easy with [PDF Split and Merge](http://www.pdfsam.org/) (imagine that)

Comment: That's a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Download (free) [Pdf Architect](http://download.cnet.com/PDFCreator/3000-2064_4-10558866.html),
go to https://editor.cutepdf.com/edit.asp and put in the amout of pages that your reader is off in the beginning of the document. Do it so that your pages now have the right numbers. Let's say that my first page is page 13. I put in 12 blank pages at the beginning of the document.

Download your file now with the extra pages in the beginning of your document. 
Open the document in adobe reader. Press print. Select the pdf-Creator printer and select to print page from the first real page (that is not the extra blank page that you have put in). In my document that would be from page 13.

Now you press print and Pdf Architect will pop up, and you can save it. When you then open the saved file you will see, that the first page has another number, in my case 13, next page 14 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

## Use Logical Page Numbers

I am assuming your digital copy of a book you have purchased is something you'd rather leave alone. So I'm advising to tweak your Acrobat Reader presentation.

1. Menu -> Preferences
2. Page display
3. Check `use logical page numbers`

Now your page navigation edit box will run accordingly to the page-displayed numbers.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably not a mistake.

The forward and introduction and "about this book" sections are not considered part of the content and so have a different page numbering system.

This is a problem in digital editions because when you tell Acrobat to go to a page, it goes to the actual page, not the numbered page. This accounts for you entering 68 and it taking you to the page numbered 51. I think you'll find there are 17 pages of preliminaries with a different numbering system.

Comment: Of course it's not a mistake – the OP already acknowledged that the introduction is numbered differently. You've basically described their problem :)

Comment: yes i know that...

but during lecture when the proff says on page 65 ...
he may say something a bit and return course and m still looking for the real page and bam i miss what he told and what he said after words and i lost link of whats going

Comment: What app do you use to read/view the docs?

Comment: any you tell me on windows i use foxit.
on Ubuntu i use the default viewer.
I can download Adobe reader too.

Comment: Ok. Adobe reader has the capability to update the pages so that it'll reflect correctly based on the document structure. The other readers don't, so far as I know. See the answer by hephaestus above for how to do this in Adobe.

Comment: will i require pro or the reader shall do?
Update: Cannot see the that option in reader

Comment: Hmmm, looking at Reader 9.5 I don't see it either. Because you're actually modifying the structure of the document according to Adobe, this is probably going to be limited to Standard/Pro versions and not available in Reader.

Comment: Hey, that works.

Answer (score 1):

Using [jPDF Tweak](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/), you can edit the page numbers and other metadata for PDFs very easily.
You just have to download the program (it's free) and pick the file to use. For other helpful things (that I haven't used yet) I suggest checking out [the manual](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/manual/index.html)

I found that recommendation in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/797326/1247472) in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried to click on the View / Read Mode and this page number is refreshed and updated when i paginate back and forth.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

The free version of [PDF-XChange Editor](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor) is able to change page numbers and to add ranges of pages with different numbering (I,II,III ...).

See their [online help](https://help.tracker-software.com/pdfxe9/index.html?command-line-options_ed.html) for documentation.

Comment: I don't see such an option with the free version of PDF-XChange Editor. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's still available. Chose "Organize/Number Pages" from the menu.