# How can I programmatically renumber pages in a PDF?

Tags: macos, pdf, automation

As a graduate student, I come across PDFs of articles and book chapters on a daily basis. Sometimes these PDFs are paginated correctly internally (that is, if an article starts on page 67, the PDF starts on page 67 as well; not on page 1). When they aren't, I have to open the file in Acrobat and renumber the pages in the "Page Thumbnails" panel.

I would *love* to be able to automate this whole process with a script (bash, Python, AppleScript, whatever) that lets me pass the first actual page number... something like `fixpagination example.pdf 67`. However, I cannot find any terminal-based program that can re-paginate PDFs. Neither [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) nor [PyPDF](http://knowah.github.io/PyPDF2/) seem to be able to deal with pagination.

Are there any scriptable programs that can internally re-paginate PDF files?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [this Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/232553/how-to-change-internal-page-numbers-in-the-meta-data-of-a-pdf).

Comment: Ooh. That looks promising. (And a little terrifying, editing the PDF directly like that.) I'll play around with this…

Comment: Hrm. It seems to be more complicated than it initially looks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12925195/120898

Answer (score 1):

There is a little python script, that can do the job: https://github.com/lovasoa/pagelabels-py

In your case call:

```
./addpagelabels.py --delete file.pdf
./addpagelabels.py --startpage 1  --firstpagenum 67 file.pdf
```