# How to fix/repair a corrupted PDF?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I had a book (PDF) in Apple Books from local files on iPad. I had 2 months worth of notes on the PDF.

Today I was not able to open it and getting an error:

> "Cannot open Document. Unable to open '' "

So I Air Dropped the file to a Mac, tried opening it in Preview, Adobe and Acrobat. Everywhere I tried the file, the file cannot be opened. It could be corrupted or damaged.

I tried to use Ghostscript (`gs`) to repair it, but it didn't work:

```
gs \
 -o repaired.pdf \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
  corrupted.pdf
```

I get an error instead:

```
Catalog dictionary not located in file, unable to proceed


**** Error: Couldn't initialise file.
               Output may be incorrect.



No pages will be processed (FirstPage > LastPage).

The following errors were encountered at least once while processing this file:
    startxref offset invalid
    xref table was repaired

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.
```

I tried updating the iPad and
restart nothing seems to fix it.

The file is about 150MB. What can I do to recover it?

Comment: Stop using the device. There are companies who specialize in file recovery.

Comment: Do you have a backup of the pdf somewhere?

Comment: yes i can share it

Comment: There exist several online repair services, for example [ilovepdf](https://www.ilovepdf.com/repair-pdf), [pdf2go](https://www.pdf2go.com/repair-pdf) and [recoverytoolbox](https://pdf.recoverytoolbox.com/online/). I don't know how good they are.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zJ9QTkZmzPfHguI1QkXDS53DkwBqvPAU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i tried those @harrymc none of them worked

Comment: @LPChip i added the link for the file

Comment: @Gantendo any companies you recommend

Comment: Your PDF is missing a few hundred bytes at its start. The PDF objects seem intact. I tried planting a header from another PDF, but this didn't work. You might need professional help.

Comment: @j.doe I live probably 5000 kilometer from your location

Comment: @KJ thanks! all i have is this corrupted version and the original document, is there anything that can be done with that ?

Comment: sorry not sure i understand, i can share the original and the corrupted versions

Comment: oh yes let me share the link

Comment: @KJ original document https://drive.google.com/file/d/11qtdLd4RFn2ovLIakJkC4Nemt5ZuIZHX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: yeh i had a lot of notes in there

Comment: oh yeh i see what you mean, im never gonna use this stupid apple books again

Comment: @KJ so basically its lost ? i dont know how to reach any specialist

Comment: convert corupted.pdf repaired.pdf

Comment: @Petepf sorry what ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been boy and man handling computer data for 59 1/2 years  and for the past 40 resolving lost data problems at various levels from dodgy switches and relays, torn paper tape and moth eaten cards, stretched tapes and cables, bent or crazed disks and flakey chips. Some amazing stories, I can not tell, or you would doubt my sanity or the people who employed me or those who infected their data.

So the first advice is cull the cause, even if that is the hackneyed "Did you switch off at the wall?"

The next step is assess the chance of recovery versus the cost of do it again.

So this was an interesting challenge and the answers are not good.

If you think there is a chance the editing device has a hidden deleted copy and the cost of replacement is exceptionally high. Then it may be worth paying for the powered down device to be forensically hooked into a diagnostic system where the disk can be mirrored and scanned for deleted `%PDF-` headers.

Modern disks tend to either not make that possible (solid state) NOR as easy as it was, by reuse the released space rapidly for large memory storage cache, thus over-write the lost data.

Now to the hub of the "Questionable" saved file.

It has retained much of the desired data. HOWEVER by comparison with the unedited  source file we can say the loss was highly significant.

The source PDF had already been edited twice, (one new cover ? & one minor tweak) so had residual oddities (not unusual but to be avoided) for adding different edits.

```
core /Size 39679 objects  
edit /Size 39692  
edit /Size 39694
```

If I restructure that source file the working count is optimised as /Size 37546 objects. Indicating there was some redundancy, but again not unusual.

The additions over 2 months should at more than a few a day be increasing the count up towards 40,000 or more. However it reports it was /Size 70957. Confirming at one time the file should have been excessively large. so the extra approx 32,000 items need to be all in the retained file but it is comparatively smaller than required.

As a test (for my comparison) I recovered just one page of annotations (without knowing which number page it covered. It may not be typical, but amounts to about 120 KB for one page.

It may not make sense here as you cannot see the components as here out of context but is the last page of changes (see the date) presumably on a Right Hand page.

[image]

We can place it over that new cover page (still not the correct unknown deleted page)

[image]

In summary my gut feeling, is that the slow cost of recovery, and low number of retained objects (count of /Annots = approx 57 (pages ?), suggests recovery is more expensive than the labour to "do it again".
Tantalisingly there is a good group from 67961 to 70957 thus those should be recoverable.

The best recovery application I found https://superuser.com/a/1808687/1769247. Is only showing objects from a nominal page number of 180 upwards to 240 from the total 849 and actually reproduces over twice as many additional image pages, since in pictorial terms some will be negatives of the soft masking so 850-1845 are pieces that may be sub image duplicates of the 180-240 or may be bits of others ?.

Here is a 30 day link to the fixed remaining parts https://filetransfer.io/data-package/nbXvfSBp#link

[image]

### Recommendations for going forward

1. Split the master file into 4 convenient parts, This has a 3 fold benefit.

   - Each part will be faster to render and respond to heavy annotation.
   - Fix any foundation problems in the source file.
   - Reduce future catastrophic loss to only 25% at a time.
2. Reconsider the annotation software's ability to work with the massive amounts of memory required and potentials for a "brownout" loss, where any temporary glitch can destroy an open editing file.
3. Work on a reliable local disk system like a workstation and never a synced cloud drive.
4. Dont use the repaired file itself, simply use that as a heads up for repeated task. May include cut and paste objects in a PDF GUI editor that should avoid any carry over of other faults.

Case specific possibility.
You may find the page numbers are off sync but correct order, or with luck the perfect order for transfer into the Master file. If that is the case then there are command line tools that "might" speed up transfer by export /Annots from recovery file as say JSON and then allow import into a suitably optimised master file by page numbers. One such tool may be coherent cpdf  as it has an optimiser tool and /Annots export import. but I cannot say if it will answer this issue well enough.

Comment: Nice! how did you extract these annotations. is there any script i can write to map these out 
if i can just extract them out i can manually place them to the right pages

Comment: if i can get like pages with just the annotations, i think that will be enough

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to write a parser script in Python or something that pulls all annotation objects from the source code of that corrupt PDF and injects them into a fresh PDF with blank pages?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pdfalyzer
https://community.metaspike.com/t/best-tool-for-pdf-forensics/1090

Comment: http://sandsprite.com/blogs/index.php?uid=7&pid=57#:~:text=view%20all%20pdf%20objects

Comment: https://book.hacktricks.xyz/generic-methodologies-and-resources/basic-forensic-methodology/specific-software-file-type-tricks/pdf-file-analysis#:~:text=For%20in%2Ddepth%20exploration%20or%20manipulation%20of%20PDFs

Comment: https://www.forensicfocus.com/forums/postid/6606708/

Comment: Haven't used one of those myself, sorry. Would start trying if it was my file though.

Comment: Nice! seems like you recovered a lot!

Comment: thats quite impressive! mind explaining how you were able to do it ?

Comment: Thank you so much!